# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"

Tags: c++, macos, arduino

mac OS X has failed to generate a make file and gives me a problem

DOLATs-MacBook-Air:~ dolatsingh$ cd Documents/ardupilot/ArduCopter/
DOLATs-MacBook-Air:ArduCopter dolatsingh$ make apm2
// BUILDROOT=/var/folders/16/slzp9s_s741cb0cgqtcddc_h0000gn/T/ArduCopter.build HAL_BOARD=HAL_BOARD_APM2 HAL_BOARD_SUBTYPE=HAL_BOARD_SUBTYPE_AVR_APM2 TOOLCHAIN=AVR EXTRAFLAGS=-DGIT_VERSION="705d3d56"
%% AP_State.o

**cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"
make: ***** [/var/folders/16/slzp9s_s741cb0cgqtcddc_h0000gn/T/ArduCopter.build/AP_State.o] Error 1

i have checked GCC version and it's 4.2.1

Comment: Ah that's a really old version of `GCC`

Comment: Looks like `C++11` support didn't begin until `GCC v4.3` and then it was very experimental. I think you need a newer version.

Comment: Also, up until gcc 4.8, the flag to enable C++11 support was `-std=c++0x` (or `-std=gnu++0x` in that case). You have two options: getting a newer version of gcc or, since you're using OS X, simply using clang.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade your IDE (if you're using the Arduino IDE).

Since version 1.5.8 of the IDE, GCC has been version 4.8.1. However, you'll need to manually enable it with the command line switch you were using.

If you  grab the latest (1.6.2 and above, currently 1.6.9) C++11 is enabled by default.

Comment: i have upgraded GCC to 4.8 and set this also as a default. even after it showing me same error.