# gcc 4.8.2 cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"

Tags: c++11, gcc, makefile, automake

I have a system in which I've been compiling programs with C++11 using automake and everything has been working.

However, when a different user take the same exact Makefile they get the aforementioned error.

Now, if they type in `g++ --std=gnu++11 program.cpp` then there are no complaints.

I've narrowed it down to a line that is causing the issue; however, I don't know how to fix it.

```
depbase=`echo no_endl.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
        g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -g --std=gnu++11 -g -O2 -MT no_endl.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o no_endl.o no_endl.cpp &&\
        mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
```

The problem is with `depbase`; however, I don't know what is going on with it or why it is there.

Below is the Automake file that I used to generate the Makefile:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = no_endl
AM_CXXFLAGS = -g --std=gnu++11
no_endl_SOURCES = no_endl.cpp
```

The only difference between my g++ and their g++ is I have an alias so `g++` turns into `g++ -g`.

Helpful information

```
g++ --version                                                          
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If there is any other information that I need to provide, then let me know.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678263/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-gnu11)

Comment: I think there should not be double dash in the switch just one `-std=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem was the `$PATH` variables for me and other users.

Now, other users have an alias for `g++` to the newer version, but their `$PATH` omits the actual location.

Make works based on their `$PATH` variable, so to fix it, I just had to make sure their path had the same location as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the following additional m4 macro file that handles corner cases of substituted C++11 compilers.

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html#ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11

Comment: As I said, if I just do g++ --std=g++11 then I'm fine.

Comment: The make files for for me and doing g++ --std=gnu++11 on the command line for them works, but the make files don't work for them.